# How to atomically update a document in RethinkDB based on old value?

Tags: nosql, rethinkdb

Let's say I have a document schema like the following:

```
{
  users: [{userid: 123, username: "foo"}, {userid: 234, username: "bar"}]
}
```

I want to add an item to `users` with username equal to a "uniquified" version of the given username. For example, if I try to add `{userid: 456, username: "baz"}` to the users list above it should succeed, but if I try to add `{userid: 456, username: "foo"}` to the above then `{userid: 456, username: "foo (1)"}` should be added instead.

Is there any way to do this with an atomic update in RethinkDB? This is a deterministic operation, so theoretically it should be possible right? If not, is there some way that I can at least detect a username conflict during the insert and simply reject the update?

I know that I can use subqueries, but it seems like the result would not be an atomic operation? All of the examples of subqueries I've seen in the documentation show subqueries on a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [consistency guarantees](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/consistency), you can combine `get` (not `getAll` or `filter` though) with `update` and have an atomic chain. Then, inside `update`, it's [described](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/update/) that if you use subqueries or something that is not deterministic, then you're not atomic and have to explicitly declare the `nonAtomic` flag.

The most verbose part in the query becomes then the way to increment the count, since you don't want to end up with multiple `bar (1)`.

The following should behave atomically, assuming you already provide:

- the id of the document, here `did = '3a297bc8-9fda-4c57-8bcf-510f51158f7f'`
- the username, here `uname = 'bar'`
- the userid, here `uid = 345`

```js
var uname = 'baz';
var did = "3a297bc8-9fda-4c57-8bcf-510f51158f7f";
var uid = 345;
// not sure readMode is necessary here, it's described in consistency guarantees
//  but not shown in the example with get/update/branch
r.db('db').table('table', { readMode: 'majority' })
// use only get to ensure atomicity between get and update
.get(did)
// update will throw if you're not deterministic, i.e. it can't behave atomically
//  here we never address anything but the current document so it's OK
.update(function(doc) {
  // this retrieves the highest index in parentheses if any
  //  put in a var because 1/ we use the result twice 2/ it's kind of verbose...
  var matched = doc('users').map(function(user) {
    // regex is /^bar(?: \(([0-9]+)\))?$/
    //  with the only capturing group on the index itself
    return user('username').match(r.expr('').add('^', uname, '(?: \\(([0-9]+)\\))?$'))
  }).filter(function(match) {
    // remove all user items that didn't match (i.e. they're null)
    return match.typeOf().ne('NULL');
  }).map(function(match) {
    // check whether we are processing 'bar' or 'bar (N)'
    //  (no captured group = no '(N)' = pure 'bar' = set index at zero)
    return r.branch(
      match('groups').filter(function(group) {
        return group.typeOf().ne('NULL');
      }).count().gt(0),
      // wrap in { index } for the following orderBy
      { index: match('groups').nth(0)('str').coerceTo('number') },
      { index: 0 }
    );
  })
  // ensure the first item in the list is the highest index
  .orderBy(r.desc('index'));
  // now we can decide on what to add
  return r.branch(
    // if there were some matches, 'bar' exists already
    //  and we now have the highest index in the list
    matched.count().gt(0),
    // add 'bar' appended with ' (N)', having N = highest index + 1
    {
      users: doc('users').add([{
        userid: uid,
        username: r.expr(uname).add(
          ' (',
          matched.nth(0)('index').add(1).coerceTo('string'),
          ')'
        )
      }])
    },
    // else, just add the user as is
    { users: doc('users').add([{ userid: uid, username: uname }]) }
  );
});
```

Hope this helps!